# Custom Entity with Custom Event in Shopware6

Tags: php, shopware

For several days I have been trying to create plugin with custom entity and event in Shopware6 because I want to add my own entity to email templates.

**What do I want to do?**

In each email template I want to use my entity: `{{ customEntity.technicalName[0] }}` (the field is loaded from the database).

so I choose this repository from Shopware github: `swag-docs-custom-entity` and I tried to create a custom event.

```
<?php
namespace Swag\CustomEntity\Event;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\EventData\EntityType;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\EventData\EventDataCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\EventData\MailRecipientStruct;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\MailActionInterface;
use Swag\CustomEntity\Custom\CustomEntity;
use Swag\CustomEntity\Custom\CustomEntityDefinition;

class CustomEvent extends Event implements MailActionInterface
{
    public const EVENT_NAME = 'custom.entity';

    /** @var CustomEntity */
    private $customEntity;

    /** @var Context */
    private $context;

    public function __construct(CustomEntity $customEntity, Context $context)
    {
        $this->customEntity = $customEntity;
        $this->context = $context;
    }
    public static function getAvailableData(): EventDataCollection
    {
        return (new EventDataCollection())
            ->add('customEntity', new EntityType(CustomEntityDefinition::class));
    }
    public function getCustomEntity(): CustomEntity
    {
        return $this->customEntity;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return self::EVENT_NAME;
    }
    public function getMailStruct(): MailRecipientStruct
    {
        $technicalName = $this->customEntity->getTechnicalName();
        return new MailRecipientStruct([
            $technicalName
        ]);
    }
    public function getSalesChannelId(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function getContext(): Context
    {
        return $this->context;
    }
}
```

and my services.xml:

```
<services>
    <service id="Swag\CustomEntity\Custom\CustomEntityDefinition">
        <tag name="shopware.entity.definition" entity="custom_entity" />
    </service>

    <service id="Swag\CustomEntity\Event\CustomEvent" public="true">
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="custom.entity" type="collection">
                <argument key="customEntity" type="collection">
                    <argument key="type">entity</argument>
                    <argument key="entityClass">Swag\CustomEntity\Custom\CustomEntityDefinition</argument>
                </argument>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument type="service" id="assets.context"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

and I edited available_entites in contact form:

```
{"salesChannel":"sales_channel","customEntity":"custom_entity"}
```

and now when I try to send the contact form, my rest is **302 FOUND** and the mail is not sent.

Comment: Will the mail be sent out without your plugin? Just to make sure, it has something to do with your plugin.

Comment: how is it possible that you're adding a single custom entity as an argument in the constructor when you add a colleciton in your services.xml. It looks as if your service definition configuration is way off.

Answer (score 0):

What does your template look like?
If the `getSalesChannelId` function returns `null` you don't have access to the `SalesChannel` in the Template. So your available entites would be:

```
{"customEntity":"custom_entity"}
```

Since it's for the contact form, you should return the sales channel id.

---

If not already done you need to add an entry to the `event_action` table, so when the BusinessEvent is dispatched the mail will be send.

Should the mail still not be send, have a look on `var/log/dev.log` may be there will the error shown.

Comment: HoelShare, I saw your repository name ExampleEventEntity and it works. but I would like to add my entity to existing mail templates. Can it be changed at all?

Comment: @symfonyshopware3 I created another repository https://github.com/HoelShare/ExampleExtendContactFormEvent
You have to decorate the ContactFormService to get your data into the existing event before it is dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

HoelShare, I saw your repository name ExampleEventEntity and it works.
but I would like to add my entity to existing mail templates. Can it be changed at all?